# Correlation analysis between two variables that each has pretest and posttest measures

Tags: correlation, repeated-measures, pre-post-comparison

Is it possible to conduct Correlation analysis between two variables that each has pretest and posttest measures? If yes, how? And if no, what kind of analysis should I be conducting?

Edit: I would like to see if mindfulness correlates well with psychological wellbeing and perceived stress. However, I collected the data in a pre and post intervention manner whereby mindfulness teaching was the intervention. Seeing that I have both pre and post scores, I was confused as to how should I conduct Pearson's correlation to see the relationship between mindfulness and perceived stress as well as mindfulness and psychological wellbeing.

Comment: Welcome to CV, ssee0003. Can you edit your question (lower left "edit" link) to expand on the details of your specific study design? What is being measured and when in who/what? I think doing so will attract more attention and some answers of better quality than you might otherwise see.

Comment: Please do not add details as a *comment* but [***edit***](https://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/360827/edit) your question to improve!

Comment: Could you maybe post two scatterplots of (wellbeing, stress) for both the pre and post measurements? That should anyway be a good start of analysis.